E0308: In a trait definition, why does Rust forget what traits a concrete type implements, unless they are explicitly declared?
I have a trait with specific bounds, for which I want to provide a default implementation of bar(), as shown in the minimal example below. However, I'm getting an unexpected error E0308. It seems that Rust either forgets that the primitive type i32 implements Mul<i32> and ignores the explicit type of the local variable a, or ignores the Output = i32 part of trait Foo: Sized + Add<i32, Output = i32>...
Rust playground
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

trait Foo: Sized + Add<i32, Output = i32>
where
    i32: Mul<Self>,
{
    fn bar(self) -> i32 {
        let a: i32 = self + 0;

        a * 1
    }
}

The error I'm getting:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:13
   |
3  | trait Foo: Sized + Add<i32, Output = i32>
   | ----------------------------------------- expected this type parameter
...
10 |         a * 1
   |             ^ expected type parameter `Self`, found integer
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `Self`
                        found type `{integer}`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:10:9
   |
7  |     fn bar(self) -> i32 {
   |                     --- expected `i32` because of return type
...
10 |         a * 1
   |         ^^^^^ expected `i32`, found associated type
   |
   = note:         expected type `i32`
           found associated type `<i32 as Mul<Self>>::Output`
   = help: consider constraining the associated type `<i32 as Mul<Self>>::Output` to `i32`
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.

Adding Mul<i32> to the trait bounds solves the issue, but I don't understand why since i32 implements it anyway.
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

trait Foo: Sized + Add<i32, Output = i32>
where
    i32: Mul<Self> + Mul<i32>,
{
    fn bar(self) -> i32 {
        let a: i32 = self + 0;

        a * 1
    }
}


Ah, that's because trait bounds are tried first and by the time the compiler recognizes it can't multiply it doesn't backtrack and so it's too late to find another implementation.

I know there have been questions on SO and on the Rust issue tracker, but for the life of me I can't find them now! So hard to search...

Looks like a known bug - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24066. Not sure if this could be made into the answer, since, well, other then the link to the issue, there's nothing really to fit there.

@Cerberus That's exactly it. Thanks for the answer.
